# Swift compiler error: Segmentation Fault 11 MKMapView

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, xcode6

I've just upgraded from XCode 6.0.1 to 6.1. Before the upgrade there was no problems

When trying to build my project I get a compiler crash, and the following errors:

> 1. While type-checking 'viewDidLoad' at .../MapViewController.swift:21:14
> 2. While type-checking expression at [.../MapViewController.swift:25:13 - line:25:37] RangeText="self.mapView.delegate = s"

In my viewDidLoad in MapViewController I've got the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  self.mapView.delegate = self
}
```

And right enough, If I comment out the `self.mapView.delegate = self`, the error for that line goes away, and jumps down to next time I call `self.mapView.someMethodCall`. I've googled a bit around to no avail. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to fix this?

Comment: Did you make a clean build after upgrading Xcode? See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998429/xcode-version-6-1-6a1030-apple-match-o-linker-error-building/25998724#25998724)

Comment: I have done that now, no change unfortunately

Comment: I redownloaded XCode and the problem went away