# Xcode 6.1 appDelegate.swift crashes on 'lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?'

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

When i was in Xcode 6 i had no problem but now that i've downloaded the 6.1 version my app crashes. I have debugged my app and found that the problem was here:

```
lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if coordinator == nil {
        return nil
    }
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()
```

When my app enter this part of code xcode says:

```
dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
0x2be220c4:  trap   //There is a breakpoint here
0x2be220c8:  nop
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this ?

Comment: Did you try a clean build? See: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998429/xcode-version-6-1-6a1030-apple-match-o-linker-error-building/25998724#25998724)