# Xcode Project Issues When Stored In iCloud Drive

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, icloud, drive

I am currently working on a few iOS and OS X projects and store them in a folder in my iCloud Drive so that I can work on them on both my peronal and work computer.  I'm using Xcode 6.1 but have also tried on 6.2.  The issue I'm having is if I make changes to a project on one computer, my work computer for example, and then use my personal one to pick up where I left off, the UI on my personal laptop is not the updated version.  It's very strange because in Interface Builder it actually shows the updated version, and all of the files for the project are up to date and how they should be.  I also use git and it says it is up to date also (thought maybe it was an issue with using git but it is the same way on projects that don't use git).  But when I run the application it's the old interface and it throws some errors at me (no errors are thrown when ran on work computer or copied to personal with flash drive).  I attached a screenshot showing what the current project looks like in Interface Builder (on the left - which is what it should look like, the newer version), and then when I run how it appears as the old version (on the right).  The file's date and time shows that it was updated the time it should be (and the difference in code proves it), but it will work flawlessly if I just copy it over with a flash drive.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

[image: Screenshot of problem]

Comment: Maybe it helps if you do a [clean build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998429/xcode-version-6-1-6a1030-apple-match-o-linker-error-building/25998724#25998724)

Comment: Thank you so much!  That worked with all of the projects.  I'm semi-new to this forum thing, I tried to vote you as the correct answer but it just gave you a one-up.

Comment: I posted that as an answer so you can mark it as correct (click the checkmark). Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You need to do a clean build:

- Clean your build folder (Product -> (Alt key) -> Clean Build Folder)
- Clean project (Product -> Clean)
- Delete derived data (Window -> Organizer -> Delete derived data)

Then build your project again.