# Swift 2.0, Xcode 7 issue

Tags: swift2, xcode7, ios9, ios8.3

I was using RAMAnimatedTabBarController Module from here:
https://github.com/Ramotion/animated-tab-bar

I developed my entire application in swift 1.2 using Xcode 6 and the app was running perfectly . I wanted to try out "side loading" of my app using Xcode 7 which has swift 2.0. I had too many errors and I managed to solve most of the errors but three.

1) This line of code which is from that RAMAnimatedTabBarController module is throwing an error saying the function can't be evoked, when this perfectly compiled in Xcode 6:

```
 var  constranints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(formatString,options:NSLayoutFormatOptions.DirectionRightToLeft,metrics: nil,views: containersDict as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

the compiler error for this was:

> Cannot invoke 'constraintsWithVisualFormat' with an argument list of
>   type '(String, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions, metrics: nil, views:
>   [NSObject : AnyObject])'

2) Another unusual error was thrown:

> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

3) And another:

> (null): error: cannot parse the debug map for
>   "/Users/Rakshith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Blubot-heabwwmhqxxvctaabxkwcpgzsadx/Build/Intermediates/SwiftMigration/Blubot/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BlubotTests.xctest/BlubotTests":
>   No such file or directory

What is actually wrong with my project? It is still set to iOS 8.3.

Comment: Blah, blah, blah, but what's the actual compiler error message?

Comment: Uh? I literally copy pasted the compiler error message.

Comment: Yeah **after** my comment.

Comment: I pasted the 1st issue after you commented the other 2 errors were already there . Anyhow do you happen to have a solution?

Comment: Yeah I have an idea about the first, which is what I was talking about as the other errors are linker errors, not compiler errors.

Comment: Okay so how do I solve the first?

Comment: Probably adding `format:` to the first parameter.

Comment: Din't work. The same error occurred again.

Comment: I am also facing last two errors with XCode 7 (beta 5), iOS 9, Swift 2.

Comment: @Vishal I've answered for solution, just scroll down.

Comment: @RakshithGb: Thanks, I tried that with no success. I am still facing linker command error.

Comment: @Vishal this usually happens when you have both Xcode 6 and 7 installed, remove them completely from your hardisk (use AppCleaner) and install Xcode 7 again. After you do this it is possible that linker error will occur again, follow those 3 steps carefully as mentioned in the answer of that tread and it will surely solve your issue.

Answer (score 9):

Disable BitCode

```
Build Settings -> BitCode
```

Comment: I don't know if this will work but RamAnimatedTabBar Controller file was updated to support swift 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to correct the 2nd and 3rd error which most of you probably will face when you're running Xcode 7 Beta as well as Xcode 6.
Just solve these two errors by following the steps mentioned in this tread:
[Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1030) - Apple Match O-Linker Error - Building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998429/xcode-version-6-1-6a1030-apple-match-o-linker-error-building/25998724#25998724)

Comment: Nope, still haven't found a solution for it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
func createViewContainers() -> [String: UIView] {

    var containersDict = [String: UIView]()

    guard let tabBarItems = tabBar.items else
    {
        return containersDict
    }

    let itemsCount: Int = tabBarItems.count - 1

    for index in 0...itemsCount {
        let viewContainer = createViewContainer()
        containersDict["container\(index)"] = viewContainer
    }

    var formatString = "H:|-(0)-[container0]"
    for index in 1...itemsCount {
        formatString += "-(0)-[container\(index)(==container0)]"
    }
    formatString += "-(0)-|"
    let constranints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(formatString,
        options:NSLayoutFormatOptions.DirectionRightToLeft,
        metrics: nil,
        views: containersDict)
    view.addConstraints(constranints)

    return containersDict
}
```

Answer (score -1):

how about to change the small code from "containersDict as [NSObject : AnyObject]" to "containersDict as [String : AnyObject]".

then I solved the issue above method.

Comment: 'NSMutableDictionary' is not convertible to '[String : AnyObject]' This is the error now.