# Updated xcode to version 7 and migrated code to swift 2. I cannot run link error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

[image]

Has anyone else come across this, and/or knows of a fix?

Comment: Clean your project: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998429/xcode-version-6-1-6a1030-apple-match-o-linker-error-building/25998724#25998724](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998429/xcode-version-6-1-6a1030-apple-match-o-linker-error-building/25998724#25998724)

Comment: clean your project and delete derived data

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. "EditaPago" needed to conform to FetchedresultControllerDelegate protocol, at least on the NSFetchedResultsChangeType method.